# Не отображается реклама AdMob

Tags: android, android-studio

Отображается блок рекламы, но самой рекламы нет.
AS пишет "Ad finished loading.", но позже выводит "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad."
Пробовал менять размеры - не помогло.
Файл google-services.json тоже есть.
В другом приложении всё отлично работает.

Код activity:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-цифры~цифры");
    setContentView(R.layout.new_app_widget_configure);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("цифры")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-цифры/цифры">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle (Module)(Часть):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**UPD**
Нужно было сделать вот так:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        super.onResume();
        mAdView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-цифры~цифры");
        setContentView(R.layout.new_app_widget_configure);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Правильное решение:**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    super.onResume();
    mAdView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-цифры~цифры");
    setContentView(R.layout.new_app_widget_configure);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```